# Lost in the maze of matplotlib's namespaces

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, pyqt4

I'm creating a custom matplotlib QWidget and i want it to be as versatile and reusable as it gets. So right now i want a method inside of QWidget to create subplots, which can be accessed for plotting afterwards. Artists come as a list in mpl but for some reason subplots don't (afaik) so they only can be accessed in consecutive order like:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
line, = ax.plot([1,2,3]) #here, artists are appended to a list, which is fine
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
line2, ax2.plot([...
```

What i have: (sorry for posting so much code but i'm really lost in mpl's namespaces, you feel me?)

```
class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Represents a canvas in QtGui.QWidget"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = Figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                               QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
```

...everything fine.

and:

```
class MplWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    """represents a custom Matplotlib QWidget"""

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.canvas = MplCanvas()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

    def add_subplot(self, nrows=1, ncols=1, plot_number=1):
        self.axes = self.canvas.fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, plot_number)
        #getattr(self, 'axes') = self.canvas.fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, plot_number)

    def draw_array(self, a):
        artist, = self.axes.plot(a) 
        self.canvas.draw()
```

What i really don't understand here is why:

```
self.axes = self.canvas.fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, plot_number)
```

is OK. But:

```
getattr(self, 'axes') = self.canvas.fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, plot_number)
```

gives me:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Am i wrong or shouldn't it syntactically be equivalent???
This would make possible to name each subplot, which would be a smooth way to access them later on (at least i hope so...)

Comment: Do you mean `setattr(self, 'axes', self.canvas...)`? The error message is pretty clear - `getattr(...)` is a function call, and you therefore can't assign to it.